# Samsung Galaxy S6 stucks at checking for updates after factory reset

Tags: samsung, factory-reset

My Samsung Galaxy S6 is stuck at checking for updates after factory reset.

I tried rebooting and resetting it again, but it didn't work. I also don't know how to flash using Odin.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Wifi during the intial setup, it will skip that screen as all updates exceed 20-30MB which is deemed too large to do on a mobile connection.